# How to load combination types of delimiters inputfile in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

How to load combination types of delimiters input file  in hive?
The input file will have combination of ""  and xml...how to load and process the data
for example the input data is -
`"hi"|"welcome"|"to"|India|<xml>data</xml>`
How to handle if this kind of issue if we face?

Thanks in advance for any idea or examples please.

I need to load the
hi|welcome|to|india|data,here how to append xml data when loading data into hive?

Comment: So some fields will have double-quotes and some won't? I'd suggest simply not putting in the double quotes when building the file.  If you can't do that, then remove them before putting the file in HDFS.

Comment: Thanks Markovitz,If the last column in xml format,how can i load the data into hive if we have  data like  welcome|to|india|<xml>data</xml>..here how can load the data ..here we have xml,how to load xml data together?

Answer (score 0):

**RegexSerDe**

```
create external table mytable (c1 string,c2 string,c3 string,c4 string,c5 string)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
with serdeproperties  
(
    'input.regex' = '(".*?"|[^|]*)\\|(".*?"|[^|]*)\\|(".*?"|[^|]*)\\|(".*?"|[^|]*)\\|(.*)'
)
;
```

---

```
select * from mytable
;
```

---

```
+------+-----------+------+-------+-----------------+
|  c1  |    c2     |  c3  |  c4   |       c5        |
+------+-----------+------+-------+-----------------+
| "hi" | "welcome" | "to" | India | <xml>data</xml> |
+------+-----------+------+-------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Markovitz,here when can we use XMLSERDE and when can we use REGEXSERDE?

Comment: XMLSERDE is used when the whole data is in XML format, not just one of the columns

Comment: After loading data into one table , In xml having different tags,how can I process this tags,Could you suggest the ways we have ?

Comment: How can we Process the data if input contains xml and | delimited  combination of data after loading data into hive using REGEXSERDE?